# Can we integrate web mail with our application?

Tags: web-applications, integration, webmail

We want to integrate webmail with our current application. At present I need to sign in to my existing application. As soon as it is done, I am asked for the webmail credentials. Once the web mail credentials are entered, the user gets access to webmail where I get 3 options in form of "Horde", "Squirrel Mail" and "Round Cube Webmail".

My client is asking me to directly redirect him to "Round Cube Webmail" as soon as he signs in to the application, thus bypassing the web mail sign in process. Can this be achieved? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roundcube is open source, you can modify it so that your application logs onto it without showing the login page.

So just edit the Roundcube's login page and have your application use the credentials stored to Login instead of the login form it uses now.